# Change file name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, javascript

I am updating a file in document library using a Put request from the client side. I need to know, how to change the file name after the file has been updated. My upload code is working fine. I can change other properties/metadata fields but not the file name.

for uploading files I am using code from [http://www.shillier.com/](http://www.shillier.com/archive/2013/03/26/uploading-files-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom-and-rest.aspx)

```
WingtipToys.Rest.Libs.upload(LIBRARY_NAME, File_Name, File_Object) // upload file
              .then(Function (data) {
                        //Update the file name property by getting the file by DOCID
                        var cc = new SP.ClientContext();
                        var targetList = cc.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('LIBRARY_NAME');
                        var targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(SP_DOCID);                           
                        targetListItem.set_item('FileLeafRef', NEW_FILE_NAME); //DOES NOT WORK
                        targetListItem.update();

                        cc.executeQueryAsync(function (data) {
                            console.log('Item updated!');
                        },
                        function (sender, args) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                        });

                        alert("Update successfully");
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                    }
                );
```

Comment: can you please post your code here.?

Comment: Code added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change file name including file extension you need to use either [copyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247198.aspx) or [moveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245487.aspx) on the [SP.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246089.aspx) object.

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
targetListItem.set_item('FileLeafRef', NEW_FILE_NAME);
```

to

```
targetListItem.set_item('BaseName', NEW_FILE_NAME);
```

Comment: I am sorry but that does not work.

Comment: I'm tested this in sharepoint 2010 and this works.

Comment: That is strange, could this have been changed in 2013 ?

Comment: Unfortunately can't check this.